# Persisting Doctrine Entity with Collection results in exception

Tags: doctrine-orm

Am working on a simple setup with two tables with a one to many (and inversed) relationship. The two corresponding entities are:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ArticlesRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles")
 */
class Article
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(name="unique_id", type="integer")
     */
    protected int $idx;

    /**
     * The inverse side
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="article")
     * @ORM\Column(name="uid", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id=new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

and

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CommentRepository::class")
 * ORM\Table(name="comments")
 */
class Comment 
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(name="uid", type="integer")
     */
    protected $idx;

    /**
     * The owning side
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="uid")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article", referencedColumnName="uid")
     */
    protected $article;

    protected $content;
}
```

Attempting to persist a new blank Article

```
        $article=new Article();
        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();
```

results in the following exception

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO articles (uid) VALUES (?)' with params [{}]: PHP Warning: Object of class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection could not be converted to float in ...\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\MysqliStatement.php line 164
```

I went searching for answers and came across suggestions close to but don't touch on this subject. One had to do with removing the type indication of the column. So I did and it gets stuck with the following exception

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO articles (uid) VALUES (?)' with params [{}]: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails...
```

When type is removed, the field defaults to type `string` which makes no difference, since Doctrine still attempts to store an empty array in an integer field (see the values in the exception above).

Question: How can I get the setup to work properly and persist all objects correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the `@ORM\OneToMany` annotation in the `Article` entity should be used on a non-existent database field. In other words, property `$id` should not be an actual field in the database table of the entity.